# looping through URLs and store data in a json file

Tags: json

I have the code below to read a XML body from a URL and save it as a .json file.

```
 var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
    var http = require('http');
    var fs = require('fs');

    var url = "http://vhost11.lnu.se:20090/assig2/index.php?table=User&id=1"
    function xmlToJson(url, callback) {
      var req = http.get(url, function(res) {
        var xml = '';

        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
          xml += chunk;
        });

        res.on('error', function(e) {
          callback(e, null);
        }); 

        res.on('timeout', function(e) {
          callback(e, null);
        }); 

        res.on('end', function() {
          parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
            callback(null, result);
          });
        });
      });
    }



    xmlToJson(url, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        // Handle this however you like
        return console.err(err);
      }

      fs.writeFile("./users.json", JSON.stringify(data, null, 4), (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        };

    });


    })
```

This works. Now I have to go through several URLs by incrementing the 'id=" part of the URL, 'id=1", "id=2","id=3" etc  and save all the data in the same json file.

```
http://vhost11.lnu.se:20090/assig2/index.php?table=User&id=1
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

quite simple actually

```js
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
    var http = require('http');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var url = "http://vhost11.lnu.se:20090/assig2/index.php?table=User&id="
    function xmlToJson(url,id, callback) {
      var req = http.get(url+id, function(res) {
        var xml = '';

        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
          xml += chunk;
        });

        res.on('error', function(e) {
          callback(e, null);
        }); 

        res.on('timeout', function(e) {
          callback(e, null);
        }); 

        res.on('end', function() {
          parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
            callback(null, result);
          });
        });
      });
    }



    for(var i = 1 i<=10;i++){
      xmlToJson(url,i, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        // Handle this however you like
        return console.err(err);
      }
      var jsoncontent = fs.readFileSync("./users.json").toString();
      fs.writeFile("./users.json", jsoncontent+"\n"+JSON.stringify(data, null, 4), (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        };

    });
    }


    })
```

you can see that at the end of the url i removed the id number and in the xmltojson function i added an id parameter, so now the function can be used in a loop, so many ids can be fetched or you can just insert a specific id to get the xml. also notice that i read the json file before writing to it so that i can get what is already in there and add to it

Comment: The output is very random and incomplete and I am getting a bunch of {
    "User": "\n"
}. Jiust to note that I am starting with an empty users.json